# Two issues with backgroundworker with progress bar WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm using WPF and I have main thread which is GUI (wizard).

When user click Finish on wizard it open second thread which display user progress bar used in background worker.

**In Main thread I doing:**

```
MessageWithProgressBar progress = new MessageWithProgressBar();
progress.Show();
createFilesInA();
createFilesInB();
createFilesInC();
createFilesInD();
createFilesInE();
createFilesInF();
createFilesInG();
createFilesInH();
createFilesInI();
createFilesInJ();
createFilesInK();
```

In each createFiles method I increment by 1 the static variable called currentStep which I used it in background worker as detailed below.

**In background worker I doing:**

```
public partial class MessageWithProgressBar : Window
{
    private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    public MessageWithProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += DoWork;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        int i = GeneralProperties.General.currentStep;
        if (i > GeneralProperties.General.thresholdStep)
        {
            progress.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                        new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate
                                        {
                                            progress.Value = 100;
                                            title.Content = progress.Value.ToString();
                                            return null;
                                        }), null);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            progress.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                        new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate
                                        {
                                            progress.Value = (int)Math.Floor((decimal)(8 * i));
                                            progressLabel.Text = progress.Value.ToString();
                                            return null;
                                        }), null);
        }
    }

    private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progress.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                        new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate
                                        {
                                            progress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                                            return null;
                                        }), null);
    }

    private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progress.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                        new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate
                                        {
                                            progress.Value = 100;
                                            title.Content = progress.Value.ToString();
                                            return null;
                                        }), null);
        WindowMsgGenDB msg = new WindowMsgGenDB();
        msg.Show();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy == false)
        {
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

The main thread updated variable called currentStep and the second thread used it to report on the main thread progress.

The operations of the main thread takes a few seconds (not more 15 seconds)

I have two issues:

1. I see on progress bar only when currentStep=2 (then the progress is 16) and then the progress is 100, and I don't see every step
2. At the beginning, the progress bar is freeze and it seems like it stuck.

(maybe it connects to the call progress.Show() from the main thread?)

Thanks!

Comment: do you set the value of the progressbar via binding ? or direct ?

Comment: @Nudity directly. See code above.

Comment: yeah got it ^^ - current step is incremented by 1 every iteration ?

Comment: @Nudity Yes, currentStep go from 1 to thresholdStep = 12. 
And progressBar.Value go from 8 to 96 and then 100 by the equation 8*i while i changed by currentStep.

Comment: Nothing increments `i` here and `ProgressChanged` is never used because you never call `ReportProgress`.  All this code worker would do is set the progress bar to 100 or something x 8 and then finish.  If this isn't what you're seeing, then you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: first try to remove the part where you set the value to 100 since this is automatically done in `Completed` and see what it changed :D + you set the value in DoWork and then in the CompletedEvent you overwrite it. use `ReportProgress()`instead

Comment: It's not clear, but if this is genuinely all your background worker is doing then you don't need it.

Comment: @Nudity See my comments in the below answer.

Comment: @Charles Mager the main thread changed the static variable called currentStep

Comment: @Programmer so your progress bar is just meant to show a single value until the window is closed? Nothing ever causes it to show a second value, it finishes after the first. What work are you doing on your background thread? As before, a [mcve] is needed here, it definitely feels like we're missing something (or you are!).

Comment: Are you sure that process between 16 and 100 % is not done in less than 100ms and that would be why you only get those progresses?

Comment: @CharlesMager I edited my question

Comment: @Programmer when your 'step' is updated, how will the progress bar get updated?  It only checks the value once. so you will only ever see some intermediate step and 100 on completion.  You are blocking the UI thread by doing all your work on the UI thread, hence the freezing.  Your work should be in `DoWork`.  I'd suggest you look at some examples of how to use `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your code your background worker is not doing anything, really. It updates the progress *once* and that's it.

Also: using global static variables to communicate between a form and a background worker - ouch...

Also, you're using it wrong in my opinion. The work (`CreateFilesInA` ... `CreateFilesInK`) should be done by the background worker - that's what it is for. As the main thread will be blocked the way you implemented it, you will not see any updates otherwise.

The usual way to implement something like this is:

1. Create progress window and disable UI
2. Start background worker that does stuff in `DoWork`. In `DoWork`, after every call to a `CreateFilesInXYZ` method, call `ReportProgress` to the the UI be updated.
3. Update stuff in progress window whenever `ProgressChanged` event is fired
4. Hide progress window and enable your application's UI when background worker is done

The way you're doing it it's in no way asynchronous. So, actually, your code should look something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    private MessageWithProgressBar progressWindow;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += DoWork;
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressWindow = new MessageWithProgressBar();
        progressWindow.Owner = this;
        progressWindow.Show();

        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }


    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
        int numSteps = 11;
        int currentStep = 0;
        int progress = 0;

        CreateFilesInA();
        currentStep += 1;

        progress = (int)((float)currentStep / (float)numSteps * 100.0);
        worker.ReportProgress(progress);

        CreateFilesInB();
        currentStep += 1;

        progress = (int)((float)currentStep / (float)numSteps * 100.0);
        worker.ReportProgress(progress);

        // All other steps here
        ...
    }

    private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressWindow.progress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    private void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressWindow.Close();

        WindowMsgGenDB msg = new WindowMsgGenDB();
        msg.Show();
    }
}
```

**Please note that the above code goes into your main window! The `MessageWithProgressWindow` does not contain any code. Maybe the `Window_Loaded` event handler is not the right place to start the background worker, but you get the picture.**

Comment: How can I define a ctor for MessageWithProgressBar on the main window? I got an error that the method must return type

Comment: I do not understand that question, really. The `MessageWithProgressBar` class will by default have a parameterless constructor. You're already calling it in your code above. Please update your question with the relevant code.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar it's a simple typo, I suspect.  Your `MainWindow` has a constructor with the wrong name.

Comment: @CharlesMager he defined ctor inside MainWindow named MessageWithProgressBar and I got about compliation error: "Method must have a return type"

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar So the constructor for MessageWithProgressBar shall be in the MessageWithProgressBar class right?

Comment: See the fixed code. The code above does not affect the progress window. The progress window is just a window with no real code. Make the progress bar public or create a property that returns the progress bar. No more. The code above goes into your main window.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar But you don't detailed in code above where you put the below code:
    public MessageWithProgressBar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
            backgroundWorker.DoWork += DoWork;
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted +=    BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        }

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a valid problem description. I'll happily modify the answer if you provide detailed information on what's going wrong with it.